# How can I track down an issue with a locked table, endless query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that is periodically getting locked in a manner that I don't quite understand. I cannot do the following:

```
select * from thetable
select count(*) from thetable
```

There are roughly 2,000 records.

I can do the following:

```
select top 2000 * from thetable
select * from thetable where ID = etc.
```

Going backwards to find a new record that perhaps was problematic, incrementing the count in chunks until I can finally reproduce it again:

```
select top 1500 * from thetable order by ID desc
select top 1550.... etc. and eventually it gets locked and never finishes the query.
```

Query never finishes... have waited 10 minutes. Only resolution is to restart the service.

The related stored procedure that I thought caused the problem I ran manually (it interacts with this table) and the longest time it took was roughly 45 seconds. This particular procedure goes through many phases and is wrapped in a transaction with a try/catch/rollback/commit. There is no explicit locking set on the procedure.

Any direction or guidance to track down the root issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using [sp_whoisactive](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/11/how-to-troubleshoot-blocking-and-deadlocking-with-scripts-and-tools/) while the query is runnig?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others use spwhoisactive or spblitzwho to find the behavior.

However I am suspecting you do not have sufficient index on that table. A better index will just make the lead blockers query run fast and avoid blocking the query scanning same table.

Also check for open transactions with sleeping status . Sometimes they create those blocking scenarios when application did not close the connection well

Answer (score 0):

You want to run something like 'sp_whoisactive', 'sp_blitzwho', etc while waiting for your select.

With those store procedure, you will get the "blocking" session and you will be able to see what it is running.